# Add text to a text box Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I can add text to a textbox using the following method:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 6")).Select
Selection.Text = "a"
```

However selecting the shape seems like poor practice.  I'd like to use something like:

```
Worksheets("Dashboard").Shapes("Textbox 6").Text = "a"
```

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TextFrame` property

`ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox 6").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello"`

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.